# Translate AFNetworking POST constructingBodyWithBlock from Objective C to Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, afnetworking-2

I'm trying to implement the PUT version of the below code in Swift (so I can implement a `PUT` with attachment), found here: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking/AFHTTPSessionManager.m

I'm having trouble getting it to compile, it says variable `task` is `used within its own initial value`. Any thoughts?

Objective C

```
- (NSURLSessionDataTask *)POST:(NSString *)URLString
                    parameters:(id)parameters
     constructingBodyWithBlock:(void (^)(id <AFMultipartFormData> formData))block
                       success:(void (^)(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject))success
                       failure:(void (^)(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error))failure
{
    NSError *serializationError = nil;
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [self.requestSerializer multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:[[NSURL URLWithString:URLString relativeToURL:self.baseURL] absoluteString] parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:block error:&serializationError];
    if (serializationError) {
        if (failure) {
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wgnu"
            dispatch_async(self.completionQueue ?: dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                failure(nil, serializationError);
            });
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
        }

        return nil;
    }

    __block NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [self uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:request progress:nil completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * __unused response, id responseObject, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            if (failure) {
                failure(task, error);
            }
        } else {
            if (success) {
                success(task, responseObject);
            }
        }
    }];

    [task resume];

    return task;
}
```

Swift

```
func PUT(URLString: String!, parameters: AnyObject!, constructingBodyWithBlock block: ((AFMultipartFormData!) -> Void)!,
    success: ((NSURLSessionDataTask!, AnyObject!) -> Void)!,
    failure: ((NSURLSessionDataTask!, NSError!) -> Void)!) -> NSURLSessionDataTask! {

    let urlX = "http://localhost/\(URLString)"  //still need to convert to baseURL

    var serializationError:NSErrorPointer = nil

    let request:NSMutableURLRequest = self.requestSerializer.multipartFormRequestWithMethod("PUT", URLString: urlX, parameters: parameters as! [NSObject : AnyObject]!, constructingBodyWithBlock: block, error: serializationError)

    let task:NSURLSessionDataTask = self.uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest(request, progress: nil, completionHandler: { (response: NSURLResponse!, responseObject: AnyObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if ((error) != nil) {
            if ((failure) != nil) {
                failure(task, error)  <-- error
            }
        } else {
            if ((success) != nil) {
                success(task, responsObject)  <-- error
            }
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Response**

The error you're getting is ***Variable used within its own initial value***, which means that you're essentially using the constant `task` before it's declared, as you're using it within its declaration.

The proper way to go around this would be to rewrite `uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest()` to return a tuple of type (AnyObject, NSError). Unfortunately, that involves even more work. My solution for your problem is to declare a few variable outside the `uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest()`, and to set them equal to the values that are captured inside the closure. Afterwards, you can call your completion blocks based on two optional binding tests, only one of which will pass.

```
func PUT(URLString: String!, parameters: AnyObject!, constructingBodyWithBlock block: ((AFMultipartFormData!) -> Void)!,
    success: ((NSURLSessionDataTask!, AnyObject!) -> Void)!,
    failure: ((NSURLSessionDataTask!, NSError!) -> Void)!) -> NSURLSessionDataTask! {

        let urlX = "http://localhost/\(URLString)"  //still need to convert to baseURL

        var serializationError:NSErrorPointer = nil

        let request:NSMutableURLRequest = self.requestSerializer.multipartFormRequestWithMethod("PUT", URLString: urlX, parameters: parameters as! [NSObject : AnyObject]!, constructingBodyWithBlock: block, error: serializationError)

        var outerError: NSError?
        var outerResponseObject: AnyObject?
        let task = self.uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest(request, progress: nil, completionHandler: { (response: NSURLResponse!, responseObject: AnyObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if ((error) != nil) {
                if ((failure) != nil) {
                    outerError = error
                }
            } else {
                if ((success) != nil) {
                    outerResponseObject = responseObject
                }
            }
        })

        if let outerError = outerError {
            failure(task, outerError)
        }

        if let outerResponseObject: AnyObject = outerResponseObject {
            success(task, outerResponseObject)
        }

        return task
}
```

**Original Response**

Why even bother doing this, when **AFNetworking** comes with the ability to make a PUT request?

https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking/AFHTTPSessionManager.m#L186

```
- (NSURLSessionDataTask *)PUT:(NSString *)URLString
                   parameters:(id)parameters
                      success:(void (^)(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject))success
                      failure:(void (^)(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error))failure
{
    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [self dataTaskWithHTTPMethod:@"PUT" URLString:URLString parameters:parameters success:success failure:failure];

    [dataTask resume];

    return dataTask;
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to implement PUT with Attachment, similar to POST with constructingBodyWithBlock, but AFNetworking doesn't have a PUT version of it.

Comment: ok, fair enough. Let me load up a project and see what I find :)

Comment: ok, I think the problem is that in Swift you're trying to use the constant `task` within it's own definition, hence the error ***Variable used within its own initial value***. Let me tinker with it for a bit longer.

Comment: Thanks @ArtSabintsev, your solution makes sense. However, when I tried it, the `success(task, outerResponseObject)` within if let doesn't get called after `completionHandler` gets called. I've tried putting `task.resume()` before and after the `if let` blocks. The original AFNetworking Objective C code doesn't seem to have such an issue, how did they resolve this?

Comment: Hey @Dean, I think the problem is that the success/failure methods get called before the network request gets called. I'll put a fix in there right now, but I'm doing it in SO's editor without checking it, so take it with a grain of salt.

Comment: Actually, the idea I head won't work, but that doesn't change my reasoning as to why my solution doesn't work. I'll have to think about this a bit.

Comment: I'd say the easiest way is to fork AFNetworking, download it, and copy/paste the POST code and rename the related parts from POST to PUT.